# Add column to condition based on parameter value SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm working in a dynamic query where i need to add a column to the query if the parameter value is false.

//SQL:

```
SET @FilterExp = 'SELECT * from tblName where ptblnFlag = '+Convert(varchar(2),@blnFlag)+') as tbl where 1=1'+ COALESCE(NULLIF( CONVERT(varchar(8000), @FilterExp),''), '')
```

In the above query i need to check if the `@blnFlag` is false then the column can be added in the where condition. If true it need not to be there.

Something like if the condition is false it should return all values and if true the result set is based on the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `AND/OR` operator's no need of `Dynamic query` here

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblName
WHERE  ( ptblnFlag = @blnFlag
         AND @blnFlag = 0 )
        OR @blnFlag = 1
```

May be am wrong with variable names but logic will be same

Comment: Its some big query which i have minimized to get better understanding.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Ok, Whether my answer is helpful or not. If no, then change the question like this. Don't use dynamic sql in question. Just say like If `@blnFlag = 0` then select query should be like `select * from...` if `@blnFlag <> 0` then select query should be like `select * from...`

Comment: Your logic worked. I have few subqueries and more complex conditions and that's why i mentioned `dynamic query`. Thanks for your time.